# EFI booting poky on minnowboard and BRIX

Tags: linux, boot, efi, intel-atom

I am trying to boot automotive grade linux (a poky build) on a Gigabyte Brix device, which is a intel atom with EFI.

The AGL image I have boots the kernel if I write it directly to a usb drive, but since the drive lacks a partition table and hence, rootfs partition it stops trying to find the rootfs.

There is a script at
https://github.com/dominig/mkefi-agl.sh/blob/master/mkefi-agl.sh that partitions the drive with an EFI fat boot partition and an ext3/4 rootfs, but if I try to boot this, I only get a blinking cursor - nothing else. If I enter the EFI shell first it complains that the shell only supports IA32 images.

The minnowboard however, which is also a intel atom happily boots this partitioned drive.

The questions I would like to have answered are: What is the difference between these two Atoms that lets one boot the usb drive, the other not and any clues to troubleshoot and get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution - turns out the EFI only was able to boot 32bit bootloaders.
updating from version F1 to F3 allowed it to boot 64bit.

the bios update I used:

http://b2b.gigabyte.com/Embedded-System/GB-BXBT-3825-rev-10#support-dl
https://www.gigabytenordic.com/update-bios-gigabyte-brix/

I had to do it blindly because this dos bootdisk it created was not able to drive hdmi, so just boot the resulting drive, type flash, cross your fingers and wait. it rebooted automatically after a while and showed version F3. Then I was able to boot the AGL image without issues.